# Pivoting a table from date range based columns to date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a table with the following structure :

```
>>> d = {'ID': ['A','A', 'A','A','B','B'], 'sub_id': [1,2,3,4,100,110], 
'start_cycle_1':['2013-05-23','2013-05-23', '2015-06-13', '2015-09-10', '2019-01-20', '2019-04-20'],
'end_cycle_1':['2013-05-27','2013-05-27', '2015-06-16', '2015-09-13', '2019-01-23', '2019-04-25'],
'start_cycle_2':['2013-06-05','2013-06-10', '2015-07-15', '2015-09-28', '2019-04-20', '2019-06-01'],
'end_cycle_2':['2013-06-08','2013-06-13', '2015-07-18', '2015-09-30', '2019-04-23', '2019-06-03'],
'start_cycle_3':['2013-06-28','2013-07-10', '2015-07-30', '2015-10-10', '2019-05-10', '2019-08-01'],
'end_cycle_3':['2013-06-30','2013-07-14', '2015-08-02', '2015-10-13', '2019-05-12', '2019-08-04']
 }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
  ID  sub_id start_cycle_1 end_cycle_1 start_cycle_2 end_cycle_2 start_cycle_3 end_cycle_3
0  A       1    2013-05-23  2013-05-27    2013-06-05  2013-06-08    2013-06-28  2013-06-30
1  A       2    2013-05-23  2013-05-27    2013-06-10  2013-06-13    2013-07-10  2013-07-14
2  A       3    2015-06-13  2015-06-16    2015-07-15  2015-07-18    2015-07-30  2015-08-02
3  A       4    2015-09-10  2015-09-13    2015-09-28  2015-09-30    2015-10-10  2015-10-13
4  B     100    2019-01-20  2019-01-23    2019-04-20  2019-04-23    2019-05-10  2019-05-12
5  B     110    2019-04-20  2019-04-25    2019-06-01  2019-06-03    2019-08-01  2019-08-04
```

From here, I'd like to construct a table indexed by `(date,ID)`. Each ID will start with he minimum date encountered in `df` and the last row has the maximum date encountered in `df` for that ID, with one row per day in between.
From the example above, rows for `ID='A'` start at `"2013-05-23"` and finish at `'2015-10-13'`.
The main column would be `"sub_ids_affected"` and would have list of sub_ids that were within a cycle (whichever it is) during that day. For example row indexed by `'2013-05-26' and 'A'`  would have `[1,2]`. Row indexed by `'2019-04-22' and 'B'` would have `['100','110']`

For `'ID' = 'A'`, **filtering out to rows where `"sub_ids_affected"` is not an empty list**, the output would be :

```
   ID        date sub_ids_affected
0   A  2013-05-23           [1, 2]
1   A  2013-05-24           [1, 2]
2   A  2013-05-25           [1, 2]
3   A  2013-05-26           [1, 2]
4   A  2013-05-27           [1, 2]
5   A  2013-06-05              [1]
6   A  2013-06-06              [1]
7   A  2013-06-07              [1]
8   A  2013-06-08              [1]
9   A  2013-06-10              [2]
10  A  2013-06-11              [2]
11  A  2013-06-12              [2]
12  A  2013-06-13              [2]
13  A  2013-06-28              [1]
14  A  2013-06-29              [1]
15  A  2013-06-30              [1]
16  A  2013-07-10              [2]
17  A  2013-07-11              [2]
18  A  2013-07-12              [2]
19  A  2013-07-13              [2]
20  A  2013-07-14              [2]
21  A  2015-06-13              [3]
22  A  2015-06-14              [3]
23  A  2015-06-15              [3]
24  A  2015-06-16              [3]
25  A  2015-07-15              [3]
26  A  2015-07-16              [3]
27  A  2015-07-17              [3]
28  A  2015-07-18              [3]
29  A  2015-07-30              [3]
30  A  2015-07-31              [3]
31  A  2015-08-01              [3]
32  A  2015-08-02              [3]
33  A  2015-09-10              [4]
34  A  2015-09-11              [4]
35  A  2015-09-12              [4]
36  A  2015-09-13              [4]
37  A  2015-09-28              [4]
38  A  2015-09-29              [4]
39  A  2015-09-30              [4]
40  A  2015-10-10              [4]
41  A  2015-10-11              [4]
42  A  2015-10-12              [4]
43  A  2015-10-13              [4]
```

P.S : Not all sub_id would necessarily have all 3 cycles.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain why line 12 is [2,3]? In the original data, isn't there only 2 in the sub_id? Also, is it okay for all missing dates to occur between maximum and minimum in the ID unit?

Comment: I fixed the line 12 (and some others), I mixed 2013 with 2015. The edit should be fine. 
I'm not sure I understand your second question ?

Comment: The fourth and fifth lines of the expected output examples skip the date. The question is whether there is a problem if it doesn't skip and the dates are consecutive, 2013-05-28, 2013-05-29 and 2013-05-30.

Comment: No that wouldn't be a problem !
As I said, this is the output filtering to only dates with non-empty lists for created column. The output non filtered should still have '2013-05-28' with [] in the third column. 
If there was any sub_id affected during that day, it would be included too so no problems there !

Answer (score 0):

Converts the data in horizontal form to vertical form and groups the values into a list of values. Add the missing date and time to the resulting data frame and fill in the values.

```
df = df.melt(['ID','sub_id'], var_name='cycle', value_name='date')
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','date'])['sub_id'].agg(list).reset_index()
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1.set_index(df1['date'], inplace=True)
df1 = df1.asfreq('1D', method='ffill')
df1.columns = ['ID', 'old_date', 'sub_id']
df1.drop('old_date', inplace=True, axis=1)

df1.head(20)
ID  sub_id
date        
2013-05-23  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-24  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-25  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-26  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-27  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-28  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-29  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-30  A   [1, 2]
2013-05-31  A   [1, 2]
2013-06-01  A   [1, 2]
2013-06-02  A   [1, 2]
2013-06-03  A   [1, 2]
2013-06-04  A   [1, 2]
2013-06-05  A   [1]
2013-06-06  A   [1]
2013-06-07  A   [1]
2013-06-08  A   [1]
2013-06-09  A   [1]
2013-06-10  A   [2]
2013-06-11  A   [2]
```